# Wrong index in button inside collectionViewCell after deletion cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView. Every cell contains button `actionButton` to remove them. Button have method `removeItem` to remove them thru attached target. I have an array `datas` contains items for collection.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        super.collectionView(collectionView, willDisplay: cell, forItemAt: indexPath)
        guard let cell = cell as? ViewCell else { return }
        let index = indexPath.row % datas.count
        let item = datas[index]
        cell.item = item
        cell.actionButton.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeItem), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```

I have a method to delete item from collection view.

```
@objc func removeItem(sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(item: sender.tag, section: 0)
    self.datas.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

But after deletion item from collection cells button index not reloaded. For example if I remove 1-st item with index [0, 0] next(second) item became 1-st but it's button index still [0, 1].

What i'm doing wrong and why button index don't rearranges?

Comment: Maybe you should reload your collection view, as well?

Comment: I tried to add `collectionView.reloadData()` next after `collectionView?.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])` but it didn't help.

Comment: Unrelated but why is your `collectionView` optional?

Comment: @AlexWoe89 No, do not reload the collection view. That's overkill just to remove one item.

Comment: @rmaddy Unfortunately I didn't find more elegant solution then `self.datas.remove(at: indexPath.item)` and `collectionView.reloadData()` after. For now it is only solution which works. I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use tags to track the index path of a cell (in a collection view or a table view). As you've seen, it fails when you can insert, remove, or reorder cells.

The proper solution is to get the index path of the cell based on the location of the button in the collection view.

```
@objc func removeItem(sender: UIButton) {
    if let collectionView = collectionView {
        let point = sender.convert(.zero, to: collectionView)
        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point) {
            self.datas.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried you approach and have to replace `let point = sender.convert(.zero, to: collectionView)` to `let point = collectionView?.convert(CGPoint.zero, from: sender)` and it didn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: Define "didn't work". Do you get an appropriate point? Then do you get an appropriate `indexPath`? And line you changed should give the same result either way.

Comment: you are right and your solution is good. My problem was in button which located deeper in view hierarchy then I expect. To catch button I have look to `superview.superview`. Here is my point `let point = collectionView.convert(sender.center, from: sender.superview?.superview)`

Comment: There is no need for that. The code in my answer is fine. Or simply do `let point = collectionView.convert(sender.center, from: sender.superview!)`. The whole idea is to convert the button's local coordinate to the collection view's coordinates.

Comment: Your solution is working fine for me but can you tell me why tag is not working for this situation ? Thanks